# Unable to push migrations to Heroku from Django

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am a student, going through a tutorial to build a website with Next.js and Django/Python. I have zero experience with this stuff and it's been a painful process so far.

At this point in the tutorial, I have created a Heroku account and have deployed my Django project to Heroku through git and have also created the postgreSQL database.

The next step, as the dude in the video says, is to migrate the data from django into the database. I've done the whole "py manage.py makemigrations" locally and then tried to push those files to Heroku as I've read in other threads, but that doesn't work. In the tutorial, the guy just runs: heroku run python manage.py makemigrations, and it works fine. This is what happens when I try it:

[image]

I don't understand what to do...I've been Googling for the last hour or so and cannot find a solution...I appreciate anyone who can help me, I'm sure it's something stupid/simple, but I am not a programmer or developer, so I have no clue at this point...

Comment: Side note: You should never run `makemigrations` on Heroku in the first place. Create migrations _during development_, commit them alongside the relevant model changes when you're happy with them, and _apply them_ on Heroku (and in other environments, as needed) by running `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Yes, I've read that before when searching for answers to this problem, but that's how the guy in the tutorial does it, lol, but yeah I'll keep that in mind. I did figure out the solution, had to just add the path to the manage.py file and that seemed to do the trick...now I apparently need to learn about fixtures and why mine is not being recognized...this stuff is frustrating, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to add the path to manage.py and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `manage.py` is not commit to your git repo, try to add it:

```
git add manage.py
git commit
git push heroku master
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working either...keep in mind, I "learned" git like 10 hours ago, haha. but when I try git commit, it says: Changes not staged for commit: shows examples of using 'git add...' and 'git restore'. then says no changes added to commit... :/